# Difference in scope between directive with template and without template AND between Angular 1.2 and 1.1?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular and trying to understand advanced directive API - I want to re-create directive template in compile function using directive element attributes.
But when I don't have a template set (or template is empty string) instead accesing isolated directive scope I access parent (controller) scope. Also - this works on Angular 1.1 but not 1.2

here is HTML:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController">
      <sandbox title="Attribute Title"></sandbox>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [], function () {});

app.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.title = "AppController title";
});

app.directive('sandbox', function ($log, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            title: "@"
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.title = "Directive Controller title";
        },
        template: '<h1>Template</h1>', // change it to: '' and Run, than change Angular to 1.2.x
        compile: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
            tElement.append('<h2> Title = {{ title }}</h2>');
        }
    }

});
```

When you Run it you get:

**Template**

**Title = Attribute Title**

But when you change template to empty string you get with Angular 1.2:

**Title = AppController Title**

And with Angular 1.1.1:

**Title = Attribute Title**

My Questions:

**Why there is a difference in accesing scope when template is set AND when it's not set?**

**Why there is a difference between Angular 1.1 and 1.2 (bug? - directive without 'template'and with isoleted scope acceses controller scope not directive scope ) ?**

**How can I build template that accesses isolated scope NOT parent scope in Angular 1.2 in compile function ?**

**Why directive controller function does not change 'title' using $scope.title = "..." - but when debugging 'scope' param in 'link' function 'title' value is 'Directive Controler Title' but it internally (WHERE to look for it) binds isoleted scope 'Attribute Value'  ?**

Here is JSFiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/yoorek/zQ66L/4/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've hit on a big change that happened in 1.2 (and a quirk in using "@").

**1)** When your template is `` Angular sees no template to apply the isolate scope to.  The reason this is an issue in 1.2 is in the answer to your second question.

**2)** This is a result of this 1.2 breaking change- [make isolate scope truly isolate](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/909cabd36d779598763cc358979ecd85bb40d4d7):

> Isolate scope is now available only to the isolate directive that requested it and its template.

So, without a template you're appending to an element that is outside the isolate scope.
From https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4889:

> As we can't distinguish markup that was originally in the html file
>   and markup that was added in the compile function the latter also
>   doesn't get the isolate scope.

and

> ...additional markup in the compile function should be replaced by using
>   the template property.
>   The idea is that the template property can also be a function. If it
>   is one, it will get the compile element and the compile attributes as
>   parameters.

**3)**  As you see above, Angular (post 1.2) is really trying to push you to use the template instead of the compile function here.  Your best bet is likely to use a template function in the manner you were using compile.  Alternatively you could use a link function with a `$compile`- but that may be adding unneeded complexity.

By appending inside the compile function you're effectively just adding to the template so it's kind of getting around this.

**4)** This has to do with the way `@` works.  From [Angulars guide to scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes):

> use attrs.$observe('attr_name', function(value) { ... } in the linking
>   function to get the interpolated value of isolate scope properties
>   that use the '@' notation. E.g., if we have this in the linking
>   function -- attrs.$observe('interpolated', function(value) { ... } --
>   value would be set to 11. (scope.interpolatedProp is undefined in the
>   linking function. In contrast, scope.twowayBindingProp is defined in
>   the linking function, since it uses the '=' notation.)

And you might also read this [SO post on the difference between @ and =](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope)

Comment: Great answer, but #4 has not been true for a while. I think ever since 1.1.x "@" will be defined in the scope in the link function. See this sample: http://plnkr.co/edit/IVfc7P1a9Kj4RQTrp7Dx?p=preview

Comment: @dtabuenc  Check out this updated plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/fH452EsTPjEJNJV0L6Xa   So I believe it's still risky to use the scope version (depending on inheritance)- but I'd be happy to be wrong.

Comment: The $scope use in the link function is fine, it is the usage in the controller that is incorrect. "@" bindings are one-way, and as such should never be written to. Any value written to it will be over-written at the next digest cycle.

Comment: @dtabuenc Note that Angular uses writing to an "@" bound variable from a controller [in their transclude example](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/3410f65e790a81d457b4f4601a1e760a6f8ede5e/src/ng/directive/ngTransclude.js).  So I'm not sure I'd call it incorrect- but risky for sure, and thus their recommendation of `$observe`

Comment: @KayakDave  In the ng-transclude they are writing to $scope.title in a controller OUTSIDE of the <pane> directive which is perfectly legitimate since it is writing to the non-isolate scope. That is natural and works fine. The problem is writing to $scope.title INSIDE a directive with isolate scope. "@" bound variables should never be written to either from a directive's controller or link functions.