# Passing variables from directive to controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to update a value from a click event.  I have a custom directive that is basically a button switch.  When the button is switched off, I want it to change the value of a certain variable to 0.  When it is on, I want it to change the value of that variable to a number > 0.

I have created a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8YOCLhoxkFeYi3TDvFqW?p=preview) to recreate the problem.

Also, I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318726/easiest-way-to-pass-an-angularjs-scope-variable-from-directive-to-controller), which was somewhat helpful, but still has me scratching my head about how to approach **my problem**.

In the directive, I'm handling the click event and then trying to change the value of the variable, but it's never being changed in the view.  I think I have to pass the value from the directive to the controller in order to propagate it to the view, but I'm not sure how to go about that.

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('buttonToggle', buttonToggle);

function buttonToggle() {
  function link(scope, elm) {
    if(elm === "#btnToggle1") {
      angular.element(elm).on('click', function() {
        var confirmResponse = (window.confirm("Are you sure?") === true);

        if( confirmResponse ) {
           scope.on = !scope.on;
           scope.off = !scope.off;
           scope.$digest();

           if(scope.on) {
              $scope.switchBtnOutput = 8044; // var I'm trying to change
              return scope.off;
           } else if(scope.off) {
              $scope.switchBtnOutput = 0; // var I'm trying to change
              return scope.on;
           }
        }

        scope.$digest();
     });
    } else {
      angular.element(elm).on('click', function() {
        var confirmResponse = (window.confirm("Are you sure?") === true);

        if( confirmResponse ) {
           scope.on = !scope.on;
           scope.off = !scope.off;
           scope.$digest();
            if(scope.on) {
                return scope.off;
            } else if(scope.off) {
                return scope.on;
            }
        }

         scope.$digest();
      });
    }
  }

  var directive =  {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: link,
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'buttonToggle.html',
        scope: {
            on: "=",
            off: "="
        }
    };

    return directive;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your directive introduces isolated scope, so directive scope.something is different from controller scope.something. Only variables you declare in scope : {...} got binded.

Btw, these directives need rework:
1. You can use ng-click in template - this will let you not to use crap digest call.
2. on == !off - so use one variable instead of 2.
3. $scope ={} << what this for.

So new template:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-toggle">
  <button class="btn btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-success':on, 'btn-default':!on}" ng-click="toggle()" ng-disabled="on">ON</button>
  <button class="btn btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-danger':!on, 'btn-default':on}" ng-click="toggle()" ng-disabled="!on">OFF</button>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
function buttonToggle()
{
  function link(scope, elm)
  {
    scope.toggle = function() {
        var confirmResponse = (window.confirm("Are you sure?") === true);

        if( confirmResponse ) {
          scope.on = !scope.on;
          scope.output = scope.output + 'Changed to ' + scope.on + '. ';
        }
    }
  }

    var directive = 
    {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: link,
            replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'buttonToggle.html',
        scope: {
            on: "=",
            output: '='
        }
    };

    return directive;
}
```

working plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/qK8TMmjoxQ7rgKraryKp?p=preview

EDIT:

And here is the [fixed plnk from the OP](http://plnkr.co/edit/8YOCLhoxkFeYi3TDvFqW?p=preview).