# How to pass a variable from a directive to a controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

How to show or hide a div in a Html, related to a controller, using the variable from a directive.

Comment: Is it a valid question? Update your code just one line of question and expecting an answer?

Answer (score 1):

To show or hide div in html use ng-show:

```
<div ng-show="myValue"></div>
```

when `myValue` is true div element will be visible ,if false then it will hide.
you have to declare that my value in controller that is true or false such as `scope.myValue=true;`

More details here: [Angularjs ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

Now passing variable from directive to controller this will help [Easiest way to pass an AngularJS scope variable from directive to controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318726/easiest-way-to-pass-an-angularjs-scope-variable-from-directive-to-controller)

Answer (score 0):

In below code I have showed ng-show and ng-hide using both examples using HTML to handle and controller to handle.

In first ng-hide hide the dhaarani name. In controller used to show the dhaarani name using

```
    $scope.hai = false;
```

inside timeout function

```
$timeout(countUp, 2000);
```

Try below code.

```js
var showApp = angular.module('showApp', [])

.controller('mainController', function($scope,$timeout) {
  
  // set the default value of our number
  $scope.myNumber = 0;
        
  // function to evaluate if a number is even
  $scope.isEven = function(value) {
    
    if (value % 2 == 0)
      return true;
    else 
      return false;
    
  };
  
   $scope.timeInMs = 0;
$scope.hai = true;
$scope.welcome = true;
    var countUp = function() {
         $scope.hai = false;
      alert("sgf");
    }

    $timeout(countUp, 2000);
  
});
```

```css
.profilename{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="showApp" ng-controller="mainController">

    <div class="page-header text-center">
       <h1>ngShow and ngHide: Functions</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- ANIMALS =========================================================== -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Type a Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="myNumber">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>      
      
      <div class="col-xs-8 jumbotron text-center">
        
        <!-- show if our function evaluates to false -->
        <div ng-show="isEven(myNumber)">
          <h2>The number is even.</h2>
        </div>
          
        <!-- show if our function evaluates to false -->
        <div ng-show="!isEven(myNumber)">
          <h2>The number is odd.</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page-header text-center">
       <h1>ngShow and ngHide: using controller</h1>
    </div>
  <p ng-show="welcome">welcome</p>
  <p ng-hide="hai" class="profilename">Dhaarani</p>
</div>
```