# Pass Directive Isolate Scope Bindings to its Controller `this` Context (AngularJS V1.6)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive, angularjs-1.6

How to pass directive parameter to its controller?

I use directive:

`<directive value="ctrl.item"></directive>`

```
.directive('directive', [ function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            value: '=value'
        },
        templateUrl: 'item.html',
        controller: 'Item as item'
    };
}])
```

I want to read `value` inside a directive's controller:

```
.controller('Item', [function Item () {

    console.log(this.value);
}])
```

Is it possible to do using **`this`**?

Comment: Just inject the `$scope` into the controller: `.controller('Item', ['$scope', function Item ($scope) {...}` and `$scope.value` should be available

Comment: @crizzis, thank you! Is it possible to use `this` instead of `$scope`?

Comment: `bindToController: true`

Comment: I tried it already, `this.value` is `undefined`.

Comment: Did the `$scope` approach work for you at all? Is it possible that `ctrl.item` is *actually* undefined?

Comment: `$scope.value` works very well.

Comment: That's weird, `bindToController: true` should work out of the box here. You can also try `bindToController: {
            value: '=value'
        }, scope: {}`, but I doubt it will make a difference

Comment: Thank you for your help!!! I'll try.

Comment: Possible duplicate with anwer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318726/easiest-way-to-pass-an-angularjs-scope-variable-from-directive-to-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Set the [bindToController property](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-bindtocontroller-) to `true`

```
.directive('directive', [ function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            value: '=value'
        },
        //USE bindToController
        bindToController: true,
        templateUrl: 'item.html',
        controller: 'Item as item'
    };
}])
```

> ### `bindToController`
>
> This property is used to bind scope properties directly to the controller. It can be either `true` or an object hash with the same format as the scope property.
>
> When an isolate scope is used for a directive (see above), `bindToController: true` will allow a component to have its properties bound to the controller, rather than to scope.
>
> After the controller is instantiated, the initial values of the isolate scope bindings will be bound to the controller properties. You can access these bindings once they have been initialized by providing a controller method called `$onInit`, which is called after all the controllers on an element have been constructed and had their bindings initialized.
>
> [— AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#comprehensive-directive-api)

---

### Use the `$onInit` life-cycle hook

```
.controller('Item', function Item () {
    this.$onInit = function() {    
        console.log(this.value);
    };
})
```

> ### `$compile`:
>
> Due to [bcd0d4](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/bcd0d4d896d0dfdd988ff4f849c1d40366125858), pre-assigning bindings on controller instances is disabled by default. It is still possible to turn it back on, which should help during the migration. Pre-assigning bindings has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version, so we strongly recommend migrating your applications to not rely on it as soon as possible.
>
> Initialization logic that relies on bindings being present should be put in the controller's `$onInit()` method, which is guaranteed to always be called *after* the bindings have been assigned.
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating from V1.5 to V1.6](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrate1.5to1.6-ng-services-$compile)

Comment: Extra `)` in `this.$onInit = function() { console.log(this.value); });`. Could you please edit it?

Comment: Done. For your reference, you can suggest edits by clicking the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42870046/edit) link.

Answer (score 0):

It should be on your directive's `scope`, and you can access it inside the `link` method like so:

```
app.directive('directive', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
        value: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'item.html',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log(scope.value);
    }
  };
});
```