# Angular modal template not displaying

Tags: templates, angularjs, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm somewhat new to Angular.  I am trying to display a Bootstap 3 modal dialog when an invalid user role is detected.  I cannot get my modal template to display.  The behavior seems to work i.e. I can dismiss the faded overlay..I just don't see the actual modal template.

Bootstrap 3
AngularJS 1.0.7
AngularJS UI Bootstrap 0.6.0

**Controller**

```
gsApp.controller('MainController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$q', '$window', '$location',     '$modal', 'ApplicationCache', 'UserService',
function MainController($rootScope, $scope, $q, $window, $location, $modal, ApplicationCache, UserService) {

   $scope.userRole = "BadRole";

    $scope.showBadRoleModel = function () {
        var showBadRoleModelInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: "badRoleModal.html",
            backdrop: true,
            windowClass: 'modal',
            controller: badRoleModalInstance,
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                    return $scope.userRole;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    var badRoleModalInstance = function($scope, $modalInstance, items){
        $scope.ok = function () {
            $modalInstance.close();
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    }
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="MainController">

            <script type="text/ng-template" id="badRoleModal.html">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3>I'm a modal!</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h2>body</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </script>

            <button class="btn" ng-click="showBadRoleModel()">Show bad role modal</button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJs UI Bootstrap doesn't work with Bootstrap 3 yet.

See more details here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/331

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reusable Angular directive that will hide and show a Bootstrap 3 (or 2.x) modal.

```
app.directive("modalShow", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            modalVisible: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            //Hide or show the modal
            scope.showModal = function (visible) {
                if (visible)
                {
                    element.modal("show");
                }
                else
                {
                    element.modal("hide");
                }
            }

            //Check to see if the modal-visible attribute exists
            if (!attrs.modalVisible)
            {

                //The attribute isn't defined, show the modal by default
                scope.showModal(true);

            }
            else
            {

                //Watch for changes to the modal-visible attribute
                scope.$watch("modalVisible", function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    scope.showModal(newValue);
                });

                //Update the visible value when the dialog is closed through UI actions (Ok, cancel, etc.)
                element.bind("hide.bs.modal", function () {
                    scope.modalVisible = false;
                    if (!scope.$$phase && !scope.$root.$$phase)
                        scope.$apply();
                });

            }

        }
    };

});
```

Usage Example #1 - this assumes you want to show the modal - you could add ng-if as a condition

```
<div modal-show class="modal fade"> ...bootstrap modal... </div>
```

Usage Example #2 - this uses an Angular expression in the modal-visible attribute

```
<div modal-show modal-visible="showDialog" class="modal fade"> ...bootstrap modal... </div>
```

Another Example - to demo the controller interaction, you could add something like this to your controller and it will show the modal after 2 seconds and then hide it after 5 seconds.

```
$scope.showDialog = false;
$timeout(function () { $scope.showDialog = true; }, 2000)
$timeout(function () { $scope.showDialog = false; }, 5000)
```

I'm late to contribute to this question - created this directive for another question. Here are some related links: [Simple Angular Directive for Bootstrap Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19644405/simple-angular-directive-for-bootstrap-modal/19644644#19644644) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/19668616/1009125

Hope this helps.