# redirecting from a modal using ng-click and the data-dismiss doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to navigate from a modal in a page to another page by adding a function to ng-click. When I remove the function assigned to ng-click, the data-dismiss works properly and the modal gets removed. But when I use the ng-click with a function, which redirects to an alternative page, it gets directed to the page, but the modal has not been dismissed. (the new page seems in the disabled state)

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addNewProject()" 
data-dismiss="modal">Add Project</button>
```

The addNewProject() function redirects to the other page and adds the details in the modal to the database.
I would like to know a way to get the page which was loaded later, in the editable way. (the modal should be completely removed.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$(".modal-backdrop").hide();
```

Adding the above line in the ng-click function got rid of the issue.

Comment: You might also need to set the `class` attribute in `body` from `modal-open` to `modal-close`: $("body").attr("class","modal-close");

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

1. Refer [Closing Twitter Bootstrap Modal From Angular Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399958/closing-twitter-bootstrap-modal-from-angular-controller)

   `$scope.close = function(result){
    dialog.close(result);
   };`

or

2. use this inside ng-click function

   `$('#myModal').modal('hide');`

Comment: Didn't seem to work. May be I am not doing it correct. Anyway, got a solution and posted it as an answer