# Angular directive used twice, override element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to write a simple directive for modals in order to get them closed when I submit the form inside them.

I have 2 modals : Loginmodal and signup modal, respectively ordered in my html.

The modals are inside a modals.html which is called with a ng-include inside a html file which is also called in ng-include, so we have here a **childscope of a childscope**

My directive

.

```
directive('myModal', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope : { },
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.dismiss = function() {
                console.log(element.hasClass('in')); //returns false
                element.modal('hide');// doesn't work because element is always the second modal
                };
            $(element).bind('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                if (!scope.$$phase && !scope.$root.$$phase)
                    scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$apply();
                });
            }
        };
});
```

I don't know why the element inside `link` is override by the last element?

I'm applying my-modal directive to both my modals but I open the first.

Any help would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `scope.$parent.$parent.$parent` is different from your two modals? If they have the same grand-old-parent, then only the last one will actually define what is that `grandOldParent.dismiss` function.

Honestly, I am a bit horrified when I see this `scope.$parent.$parent.$parent` thing. It is alway recommended to avoid using `$parent`, so chaining 3 of them is even crazier.

Do you really need an isolated scope (`scope: {}`) if in fact you manipulate its upper parents? Why not using an inherited scope?

There is probably a cleaner way to deal with these scopes. Are you using, or have you looked at https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ where modals are angularized using a `$modal` service on which you define template and controller?

Also this is useless:

```
if (!scope.$$phase && !scope.$root.$$phase)
  scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$apply();
});
```

And should be replaced by

```
if (!scope.$root.$$phase) {
  scope.$apply();
}
```

(or simply `scope.$apply` if this event is asynchronous and outside of Angular digest cycle).

Also be aware that `scope.$apply` does in fact a `$rootScope.$digest` so it *doesn not* matter which scope you $apply.

**UPDATE**: What you could do is add a `ng-click="close"` in your directive html, and add that to its link function:

```
scope.close = function() {
  // do stuff on this directive instance
  console.log(element.hasClass('in'));

  // close the modal
  var parent = scope;
  while (!parent.dismiss) { parent = parent.$parent; }
  parent.dismiss();
}
```

This way each instance of your directive has its own `close` function (so doesn't override any other one) but still calls the unique `dismiss` that belongs to the one modal every instance use.

Comment: I know it's ugly to use the $parent.$parent.$parent. The inner developer of myself, tells me that this is crap and there should be something simpler.
I don't think the `scope.$parent.$parent.$parent` is different for the two modals because they're in the same file.
I'll try to fix stuff and be back to you.

Comment: for the Edit, It's not yet available for Angular 1.3

Comment: Ok, then how do I make it for that the directive doesn't override the first modal? 
Thank you for your time

Comment: I'm using an older verison of angular bootstrap with angular 1.3 (even tried 1.4.0-beta.6) and it works like a charm. It alows a code way cleaner where you only load a modal template when you actually need it and with its own controller.

Comment: Well I don't know what you're trying to do by overriding this parent parent parent dimiss method. Couldn't you just write `scope.dimiss = ...` ? try with `scope: true` instead of `scope: {}`

Comment: The thing is I can't install it with bower. Conflict in dependencies.

Comment: Ok did the replacements mentioned in your last comment : 
When I call $scope.dismiss(); I get >undefined is not a function
Which means it's not in the scope.

Comment: Did you miss the fact that my modals are in 2 levels of ng-include ?

Comment: Any way you could reproduce that in a minimalist code into a jsfiddle? that would really help get you the best answer

Comment: ng-include create inherited scopes so you should still be able to access `scope.dismiss` without reaching a parent

Comment: I'm creating the plunker. It would take some time, so forgive me please if it gets late.
I think when applying the same directive on two modals in the same file, the second overrides the first definition of dismiss

Comment: @Sekai I've added a workaround in my answer (see update). It is still not clean but should at least avoid your issue. I also try to reach `dismiss` by browsing parents one by one so you are not dependent on a strict scope hierarchy. I guess it is the trade off when trying to combine vanilla bootstrap modals with angular.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Actually I'm closing the modal after a successful login/ signup , so I don't think ng-click would do the job for me

Comment: I actually got inspired from this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19668616/3062150
but it seems it wouldn't work when you apply the same directive attribute to 2 different modals in the same file, one would override the other..

Comment: Any event is fine, as long as the logic is within your directive code and not in that shared `dismiss` function.