# Can I watch for changing attibutes in directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Can I watch for changing attributes in directive?

I have something like this:

```
<online-wathers></online-watchers>
```

It shows online connected users to the video broadcast and requires a broadcast-id. Obviously without this attribute it won't work. 
This video broadcast starts not on document ready, but when a publisher actually wants to start it. And when he starts - the backend gives me the broadcast id.

For now I just append it to the DOM with broadcast-id="xx" when api returns me broadcast-id.

```
$(".online-watchers-container")
      .html($("<online-watchers broadcast-id='"+broadcast.id+"' />"));
$(".chat-container")
      .html($("<chat broadcast-id='"+broadcast.id+"' />"));
$(".request-container")
      .html($("<live-requests broadcast-id='"+broadcast.id+"'></live-requests>"));

// compile directives
angular.bootstrap(angular.element("online-watchers, chat, live-requests"), ['MyApp']);
```

But is there any internal way to watch adding or changing an attributes? So on page load I will already have *<online-watchers></online-watchers>* in DOM and when I get response with broadcastId i just add attribute to element in DOM and directive reacts on it.

Please, if you treat it like shit-code, I'll much appreciate if you show some examples of better solution.

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you to start by reading this. You are doing many many things wrong right now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Comment: For the core part of the question: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive (Section: Attributes)

Comment: @fastreload, thanks, i read this before. it's like a needed solutoin and I don't see (for now) any other.. That's why I'm asking for a better solutions here.

Comment: The Attributes part, the example starting with $observe is what you are looking for indeed

Comment: Thanks, can you throw some example of $observe in plunkr? I was doing it as well, but not worked for me.. ?

Comment: Nope, you can $watch with the current scope in the directive. This would also help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371159/angularjs-how-to-get-evaluated-attributes-inside-a-custom-directive/12372494#12372494

Comment: haha I'm just lookin your answer there :) Thanks! I'll try it

Comment: @fastreload, will you please look at this? http://plnkr.co/edit/gOSlGVBTHa1os7sfDfv9 I've just really solved my question with your help. Want to post all your comments in Answer form? I'd approve it.. Thanks

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/b0a0jX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can

```
function MyDirective() {
    return {
        link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            scope.$watch(iAttrs.scopeProp, function (val) {
                console.log("prop: " + val);
            });
            iAttrs.$observe("interpolated", function (val) {
                console.log("interpolate: " + val);
            });
        }
    }
 }
```

.

```
<my-directive scope-prop="someId" interpolated="{{someId + 1}}"
```

.

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.someId = 12;
}
```

For more examples, check out: [How to get evaluated attributes inside a custom directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371159/angularjs-how-to-get-evaluated-attributes-inside-a-custom-directive/12372494#12372494)

Comment: I don't think you want to use $observe with `scope-prop`, since the value of that attribute is just a string (it is not interpolated), hence it will never change.  The console log shows `prop: someId`.  The $observe callback function for `scopeProp` will never be called again.

Comment: Indeed I don't, I was not careful enough. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Yea, finnaly i've choosed $observe, end set an attribute like <chat broadcast-id={{broadcastId}}></chat> and it works as well if I set broadcast-id="123". that's what i wanted. Thanks for your help :)