# Angular.js: How does $eval work and why is it different from vanilla eval?

Tags: angularjs

I was curious about the `$scope.$eval` you so often see in directives, so I checked out the source and found the following in `rootScope.js`:

```
  $eval: function(expr, locals) {
    return $parse(expr)(this, locals);
  },
```

`$parse` appears to be defined by `ParseProvider` in `parse.js`, which appears to define some kind of mini-syntax of its own (the file is 900 lines long).

My questions are:

1. What exactly is `$eval` doing?  Why does it need its own mini parsing language?
2. Why isn't plain old JavaScript `eval` being used?

Comment: $eval evaluates an _Angular_ expression _against/on the current scope_.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

`$eval` and `$parse` don't evaluate JavaScript; they evaluate AngularJS [expressions](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). The linked documentation explains the differences between expressions and JavaScript.

**Q: What exactly is $eval doing? Why does it need its own mini parsing language?**

From the docs:

> Expressions are JavaScript-like code snippets that are usually placed in bindings such as {{ expression }}. Expressions are processed by $parse service.

It's a JavaScript-like mini-language that limits what you can run (e.g. no control flow statements, excepting the ternary operator) as well as adds some AngularJS goodness (e.g. filters).

**Q: Why isn't plain old javascript "eval" being used?**

Because it's not actually evaluating JavaScript. As the docs say:

> If ... you do want to run arbitrary JavaScript code, you should make it a controller method and call the method. If you want to eval() an angular expression from JavaScript, use the $eval() method.

The docs linked to above have a lot more information.

Comment: You said $eval not actually evaluating JavaScript but if I do $eval("{id: 'val'}") I get a JS object. (Angular 1.0.8)

Comment: @Yappli `$eval` doesn't evaluate JavaScript; it evaluates AngularJS expressions, which are kind of like a safer subset of JavaScript. `"{id: 'val'}"` is a valid AngularJS expression and should return a valid JS object. See the link above for difference between expressions and regular JS.

Comment: Nice answer but I'm not sure that "e.g. no control flow statements" is accurate. You can do something like this... ng-click="someVal ? someFunc(someVal) : noop" which is a perfectly valid angular expression

Comment: @CharlieMartin The documentation specifically says ["no control flow statements"](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), but your point is valid. However, I definitely wouldn't recommend doing that in an ngClick; that kind of logic almost certainly belongs in the controller.

Comment: Interesting that the docs say that as the support for the ternary operator was intentionally added...
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/parse.js#L587-601
The ng-click was just a simple example and I agree that logic should be in a controller, but I don't see anything wrong with using a ternary operator in the bracket notation and the angular team obviously doesn't either or they wouldn't have added support for it. I suppose if a correction were to be made, it should happen in the docs before this answer though

Comment: I'm not arguing with the usefulness of the ternary operator *generally*, but just the wisdom of using it in the specific case of API control flow with `ng-click`. But anyway, the ternary operator was added somewhat recently and when I wrote this answer (and probably when the docs were last upated) it was not supported and there were *truly* no control flow statements supported. Either way, I updated the answer. :-)

Comment: What you're talking about is called expression sandbox and will be removed on Angular 1.6: https://angularjs.blogspot.com.ar/2016/09/angular-16-expression-sandbox-removal.html

Answer (score 22):

From the test,

```
it('should allow passing locals to the expression', inject(function($rootScope) {
  expect($rootScope.$eval('a+1', {a: 2})).toBe(3);

  $rootScope.$eval(function(scope, locals) {
    scope.c = locals.b + 4;
  }, {b: 3});
  expect($rootScope.c).toBe(7);
}));
```

We also can pass locals for evaluation expression.

Answer (score 3):

I think one of the original questions here was not answered. I believe that vanilla eval() is not used because then angular apps would not work as Chrome apps, which explicitly prevent eval() from being used for security reasons.