# directive without scope setting value undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my angular app, I've to use different directives on a single field.

here are my directives

```
angular.module('app')  
.directive('focusMe', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        scope: { trigger: '@focusMe' },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {

            scope.$watch('trigger', function (value) {
                if (value === "true") {

                    $timeout(function () {
                        element[0].focus();
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and another one for datepicker

```
.directive('ngDatepicker', function() {
return {
restrict: 'A',
replace: true,
scope: {
  ngOptions: '=',
  ngModel: '='
},
template: "<div class=\"input-append date\">\n  <input type=\"text\"><span class=\"add-on\"><i class=\"icon-th\"></i></span>\n</div>",
link: function(scope, element) {
  scope.inputHasFocus = false;
  element.datepicker(scope.ngOptions).on('changeDate', function(e) {
    var defaultFormat, defaultLanguage, format, language;
    defaultFormat = $.fn.datepicker.defaults.format;
    format = scope.ngOptions.format || defaultFormat;
    defaultLanguage = $.fn.datepicker.defaults.language;
    language = scope.ngOptions.language || defaultLanguage;
    return scope.$apply(function() {
      return scope.ngModel = $.fn.datepicker.DPGlobal.formatDate(e.date, format, language);
    });
  });
  element.find('input').on('focus', function() {
    return scope.inputHasFocus = true;
  }).on('blur', function() {
    return scope.inputHasFocus = false;
  });
  return scope.$watch('ngModel', function(newValue) {
    if (!scope.inputHasFocus) {
      return element.datepicker('update', newValue);
    }
  });
}
  };
});
```

it throws me an error

> Multiple directives asking for new/isolated scope

after hours of searching and working on different solutions, i finally understand this one [same like my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22303715/2660342) and changed my first directive like this

```
angular.module('app')  
.directive('focusMe', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$watch(attr.focusMe, function (value) {
                if (value === "true") {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        element[0].focus();
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
})
```

But now its not working because it always gives me `value = undefined` and I don't know why it is happening. May be I'm missing something here or not doing it properly??

here is my html where I'm binding its value

```
<input type="text"  focus-me="{{ DateOfBirthFocus }}" ng-datepicker>
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: first things first: is DateOfBirthFocus assigned?

Comment: yes it is set to true in controller

Comment: Beware of double binding boolean values: they are copied by value, not for reference, so maybe you'll be missing a "change" in the variable.

Comment: I didn't get you @Luxor001

Comment: consider this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014471/how-to-bind-boolean-values-in-angular-directives

Comment: it helped me to resolve my issue but I'm getting another issue that focusMe directive find those elements null where I've defined ng-datepickr directive. (eg datepicker field always be null for focusMe directive)

Comment: please share some code in a plunker or something, i can't look forward your issue without it.

Comment: that's because you ng-datepicker it's **replacing** your element (it's a directive with replace: true, assuming you are using bootstrap angular < 2.0) Try to update your libraries of bootstrap and see if it resolves your issue.

Comment: issue was in initialization of ng-model value. i was initializing it like this *$scope.DateOfBirthFocus  = ''* but the correct way is *$scope.DateOfBirthFocus  = {}* now I'm getting object in ng-model.