# Why does the link function of my directive never get called?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have this directive:

```
    hpDsat.directive('ngElementReady', [function() {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function($scope, $element, $attributes) {
                // put watches here.
                console.log(" WHAT THE @#%*%$??? ");
                $scope.$eval($attributes.ngElementReady);
            }
        };
    }]);
```

I never see the output of the `console.log`. I'm declaring an element like this:

```
<div data-ng-element-ready="console.log(' ------------------------------- COMPILED! ')" data-ng-if="analysis.type" data-ng-show="showBasicHtml" data-ng-include="analysis.type+'Content.html'"></div>
```

Yes, I am declaring the directive before I declare the controller under which the `div` element exists. The element appears, ngShow and ngInclude works, and anything in the loaded template works just fine too (more directives, controllers, {{expressions}}, etc).

If I execute it with a compile function, the compile function *does* work, but still not the link function:

```
    hpDsat.directive('ngElementReady', [function() {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            compile: function($element, $attributes) {
                console.log("This I do see."); // THIS WORKS!!
                return function($scope) {
                    // put watches here.
                    console.log("But not this. Why???"); // DOESN'T WORK!!
                    $scope.$eval($attributes.ngElementReady);
                };
            }
        };
    }]);
```

The console.log of the compile function works fine, but the returned link function still never gets executed.

Any idea why the link function might not get fired?

Comment: Found the problem. I commented it in Eduard Gamonal's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error might be somewhere else. I tried it in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egamonal/S53eA/) and the first version works.

**eval()**

In any case, you might have a missunderstanding about what `$scope.$eval()` does:

`$scope.$eval()` evaluates angularjs code against a scope. JavaScript's `eval()` function to run arbitrary js code in angularjs is `$window.eval()`. More about this here: [Angular.js: How does $eval work and why is it different from vanilla eval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671471/angular-js-how-does-eval-work-and-why-is-it-different-from-vanilla-eval)

I tested the directive isolated from the controller:

```
<div data-ng-element-ready="console.log('COMPILED!')"></div>
```

and the directive:

```
app.directive('ngElementReady', ['$window', function($window) {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function($scope, $element, $attributes) {
        console.log("Reached the link fn", $attributes);
        $window.eval($attributes.ngElementReady);
    }
};
}]);
```

I do get the value "reached the link fn" and `$attributes` is correct:

```
Reached the link fn Object { $$element={...}, $attr={...},  
ngElementReady="console.log('COMPILED!')", more...}
```

And `$window.eval()` returns `COMPILED!`

and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/egamonal/S53eA/1/) with a controller.

in any case, using `eval()` to execute code written in an attribute looks dangerous. Anybody can modify the DOM to run code there. At least make sure that it won't affect any other users or server-side.

**Reproducing the problem with ng-if**

Edited after first comment:
I tried making the ng-if expression evaluate to false [here](http://jsfiddle.net/egamonal/S53eA/2/)
This time it doesn't show the message.
This probably happens because in order to evaluate ng-if, yuo must compile first the directive. otherwise, it's just code that anuglarjs isn't aware of. However, because it is removed from the DOM, it never reaches the link function.

**Execution order of AngularJS functions**

In general, the order of execution goes like this ([Josh David Miller explains it](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/bBgJ6Tb-mHo/PDSU76pNPtAJ):

```
<div directive1>
  <div directive2>
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Now AngularJS will create the directives by running directive functions in a certain order:

```
directive1: compile
  directive2: compile
directive1: controller
directive1: pre-link
  directive2: controller
  directive2: pre-link
  directive2: post-link
directive1: post-link
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on eval. I won't use that aftwr all, but the console.log line which is before it sgould execute, even if the $eval doesn't work, right? I don't see why mine doesn't. The problem is I have tons of code so I can't really fiddle it. If i make a fiddle, it will probably work because it's so simple. I wonder in general what might cause a link function to be ignored.

Comment: maybe you can start checking ng-if? normally you don't use ng-if and ng-show in the same directive, because ng-if removes the element from the DOM and ng-show just hides it.

Comment: hey @trusktr I edited my answer to give you some more hints. check the value of your `analysis.type` variable. maybe you can force it to be true and see what happens, or remove the `ng-if` attribute?

Comment: Thanks for the insight! You helped me find the problem: If the value of analysis.type used in the ngInclude directive doesn't cause a matching template to be found, then the link function of my ngElementReady directive doesn't execute. As soon as I set the value of analysis.type (at some time in the future) to some value that causes a template to be found, then I see the link function output. This is actually good, as it lets me run stuff when the "element ready".