# Pass variable to AngularJS directive without isolated scope and updating it

Tags: angularjs, binding, directive

I want passing variables to AngularJS directive without using isolated scope.
I need this variables are updated, and not static.
I read this example, the last answer:

[Directive scope attributes without an isolated scope in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651250/angularjs-directive-scope-attributes-without-an-isolated-scope)

But it works only with string, and not object.

Comment: why don't you wanted to use `isolated scope`?

Comment: This is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900201/how-to-access-parent-scope-from-within-a-custom-directive-with-own-scope-in-an. I think `scope: true` is what you're looking for.

Comment: I cannot use isolated scope because I have to access to scope controller, and I'm passing dinamic parameters, in same directive