# How to use $eval to pass string to obj - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this string:

```
"var config={general:{instance:'livedemo'}};"
```

And I want to create an object based on that string,

the thing is that using the normal JS eval function everything works great,
but using $eval I get "ReferenceError: config is not defined" and angular only let me use $eval on the controller.

someone with an idea of how I can do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question might have your answer, [Angular.js: How does $eval work and why is it different from vanilla eval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671471/angular-js-how-does-eval-work-and-why-is-it-different-from-vanilla-eval)

> $eval and $parse don't evaluate JavaScript; they evaluate AngularJS [expressions](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). The linked documentation explains the differences between expressions and JavaScript.

I tried the expression evaluator for angularjs 1.0.8+ at the linked page. It is working without giving any exceptions. If you want to set some data in at a key config on the scope, i.e. `scope.config`, then you can discard the keyword `var`.

```
"config={general:{instance:'livedemo'}}"
```

Comment: Thanks Rubish, as you said the problem was the "var" keyword :)

Answer (score 0):

Angular's `$eval` is not made to evaluate any javascript expression but an angular expression, i.e. usually what you write into your HTML such as `{{expression}}`

Now it all depends on where your string to be evaluate comes from. If you have total control over it it is fine to do an `eval`. However if you are not sure it is safe, you can try to parse it.

If your string into the `{}`was proper JSON, i.e.: `{"general": {"instance": "livedemo"}}`, then you could have:

```
var s = "var config={general:{instance:'livedemo'}};"
var m = s.match(/var (.*)=({.*})/);
var varname = m[1];          // "config"
var data = JSON.parse(m[2]); // {general: ...}
```

Comment: first thanks for the replay, but my string is doesn't have the right Quotes("), so I can't use the JSON.parse, any other idea of how to do it?

Comment: Well then you will need to use `eval`, but maybe you could find a way to avoid the whole thing? Where does this string-code come from? You could evaluate only m[2] and make sure no funciton is invoked by removing any parenthesis: `eval("var data = " + (m[2].replace(/\(\)/,''))); `