# Evaluate string in dot notation to get the corresponding value from an object in the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Really hoping someone can help me with a problem I've had a couple of times recently.

Let's say I have two objects in AngularJS.

```
$scope.fields = ['info.name', 'info.category', 'rate.health']

$scope.rows = [{
    info: { name: "Apple", category: "Fruit"},
    rate: { health: 100, ignored: true}
},{
    info: { name: "Orange", category: "Fruit"},
    rate: { health: 100, ignored: true}
},{
    info: { name: "Snickers", category: "Sweet"},
    rate: { health: 0, ignored: true}
}]
```

I would then like to display a table in a view that shows only the fields in the `$scope.fields`. This would be super easy if the table was flat, and I know I could flatten it using JavaScript, but there must be a way to do this by converting the dot notation to the path.

I have added a JSFiddle to demonstrate the problem I'm having:

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/7dyqw4ve/1/

I have also tried doing something as suggested below, but the problem is its terrible practice to use functions in the view:
[Convert JavaScript string in dot notation into an object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference)

If anyone has any ideas I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The approach suggested in your linked question seems sound - can you not just wrap that in a filter?

Comment: I thought about that too but (and excuse me if I'm incorrect), from a performance point of view, would you be sending the full dataset to a filter multiple times therefore decreasing the speed at which the entire collection of rows would be run? Genuin question

Comment: Plus you should be really careful while using filters on DOM especially if it does extensive operation, filters run as many times as it takes to stabilize during a single digest cycle. You could as well have the controller set up the view model on the scope appropriately.

Comment: Sure thing - they're good points and you're absolutely right. I'd typically keep an in-memory cache in the filter for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case you can make use of angular's built in evaluator exposed via the property **[`$eval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval)** on the scope ([*not the vanilla **`eval`***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671471/angular-js-how-does-eval-work-and-why-is-it-different-from-vanilla-eval)) to evaluate **any angular expression** (not for evaluating javascript as *eval* does). Angular internally uses this to evaluate the expression on the scope while resolving the bindings.

Example:-

```
{{$eval(field, row)}}
```

You could do:-

```
 <th ng-repeat="field in fields">{{$eval(field, row)}}</th>
```

or wrap the logic in the controller and expose it via a method on the scope.

```
  <th ng-repeat="field in fields">{{getValue(field, row)}}</th>
```

and

```
$scope.getValue = function(exp, row){
    return $scope.$eval(exp, row);
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s8okoec3/)**

You could as well use [`$parse`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) (inject `$parse`) service.

```
$scope.getValue = function(exp, row){
    return $parse(exp)(row);
}
```

and

```
<th ng-repeat="field in fields">{{getValue(field, row)}}</th>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxymq762/)**

Comment: Thanks @PSL. Do you know if this would be considered under **eval is evil**? Is it bad practice, or acceptable under these circumstances?

Comment: @Mark This is not the `eval`

Answer (score 0):

A minor variation on [PSL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28976380/4236417) that also works:

```
<th ng-repeat="field in fields">{{$eval('row.'+field)}}</th>
```

The `$eval('row.'+field)` first results in `row.info.name` for `fields[0]`, for example.  And then the binding `{{row.info.name}}` results in `Apple`.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tbmpls/xhon86p7/8/

Nice, simple and easily understandable, I think.

It *seems* that performance should be roughly equivalent to a straight `{{row.info.name}}` binding because creating the string should be incredibly quick - but interested in anyone's comments on this.

(Btw, this also works inside an ng-repeat where your list is nested in an object like :

```
<span ng-repeat="val in $eval('myobj.'+myPathInDotNotation) track by $index">
```

but as with all things ng-repeat, you will definitely want to check performance on this)