# Evaluate an expression from within a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have an Angular app where data is loaded in through JSON files. For the various objects, one of the properties is a "Description". In my app I pop it in my html via `{{item.Description}}`. My problem is that the string in the JSON file has values that need to be adjusted based on a variable. For example, "The value is 160 (+20 per var)". I would like this description to read out 160 plus 20 times the value of the provided variable.

Unfortunately I can't just put `{{160+(20*var)}}` in the description, because it just prints out the expression as string.

Is there anyway to create that binding in angular so it updates dynamically based on the other variable?

**Update**
As per request I'm adding as much code as I can.

In my file's head I'm including a JSON file with:

```
<script src="path/to/file.json"></script>
```

Then, I have my controller:

```
app.controller('itemController', function(){
    this.items = Items //Items is declared in the JSON file as the JSON object.
});
```

Then in my HTML I call:

```
<div ng-controller="itemController as ctrl">
    <span class="description" ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items">
        {{item.Description}}
    </span>
</div>
```

The problem is, that `item.Description` has expressions I would like to evaluate. I would normally just do `{{160+(20*ctrl.var)}}`, but since that expression is contained in the `item.Description` string, Angular doesn't evaluate it normally.

Comment: Could you share some code? The requirement is not very clear, it would be really helpful to see some code.

Comment: @RocoCTZ There is no relevant code yet really. All I'm doing is including a JSON file, assigning it to a variable and then outputting it to the file. I'll update my question with some code, but there is nothing really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you can do this by replacing `{{item.Description}}` with `{{$eval(item.Description)}}`, which will evaluate a string as an Angular expression. See the [Angular docs for expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), or [a StackOverflow post about $eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671471/angular-js-how-does-eval-work-and-why-is-it-different-from-vanilla-eval).

**Edit:** OP has clarified that `item.Description` may contain mixed Angular expressions and other text, for example `"The value is {{85 + 22 * ctrl.var}}"`. Fortunately [the Angular docs for $compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) contain an example that solves this exact problem! Here is a brief demo.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('compile', function($compile) {
    // directive factory creates a link function
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(
        function(scope) {
           // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
          return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
        },
        function(value) {
          // when the 'compile' expression changes
          // assign it into the current DOM
          element.html(value);

          // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
          // scope.
          // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
          // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
          $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
      );
    };
  })
  .controller('itemController', function() {
    this.var = 5;
    this.items = [
      {Description: "What's 1+1? It's {{1+1}}"},
      {Description: "The value is {{85+22*ctrl.var}}"},
      {Description: "He{{'llo'}} World!"}
    ];
  });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#main > span {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" class="ng-scope">
  <h1>Compile Test!</h1>
  <div ng-controller="itemController as ctrl" id="main">
    <span class="description ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items" compile="item.Description"></span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: When I try running that I get a Error: `$parse:syntax Syntax Error`. It doesn't like the {{ in the `item.Description`. Upon reading the links I notice mention of special syntax, but can't find it...

Comment: Could you simply not output the {{ }} in `item.Description`? If not, you can remove it manually with a loop inside the controller.

Comment: I've changed `item.Description` to have it without the {{ }}, so I have 85+(22*var) and I still get a syntax error starting at the 85

Comment: I see the problem. `$eval` produces an error when I try to use it on string, which is what `item.Description` is. I need it to evaluate the expression in the middle of a string.

Comment: No, `$eval` is supposed to take a string... if you put `{{ 85 + (22 * var) }}` directly into the body, does it work correctly?

Comment: if I change `item.Description` to "85+(22*var)" it does the appropriate calculation and outputs the right number. If I put {{85+(22*var)}} in the same spot as `{{$eval(item.Description)}}` it outputs the right number. As soon as I put text into `item.Description` I get a syntax error.

Comment: So it works as I expected, but perhaps not as you did. Do you mean that the description will be a mix of text and Angular expressions, for example, `The value is {{85+22*var}}`?

Comment: Yes, what I meant when I said string was Text in addition to the expression. I need the description to be a combination of text and an expression such as `The value is {{85+22*var}}`