# Not able to use eval() with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, eval

I am trying to use `eval` from javascript to call a function in angular.js. I have its name in string

I used the following:

```
$scope.$eval("$scope.drawFactory.draw")({},$scope.paint);
```

But it's showing

`TypeError: $scope.$eval(...) is not a function`

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: duplication with: [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671471/angular-js-how-does-eval-work-and-why-is-it-different-from-vanilla-eval)

Comment: If the format is the same you dont really need eval. You could do something like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VabERy

Answer (score 1):

You could pass `expression(string)/function` to `$eval` which will evaluated against controller scope. No need to use `$scope` for `$eval` string.

```
$scope.$eval("drawFactory.draw")
```

Where as you are doing `$eval` function & again calling that function call by

```
//below is obviously gonna throw an error
$scope.$eval("$scope.drawFactory.draw")({},$scope.paint); //incorrect function execution
```