# How to invoke a function as dynamically string in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scope, angularjs-ng-click

How to use a *`function assigned variable`* in `ng-click?`? I have tried **three** ways below, but that's also not working.

Could you please let me know is it possible or not??? if yes, then how?

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("name", function($scope) {

 $scope.showname = function()
 {
 alert("Ramesh");
 }
 
 $scope.variable1 = $scope.showname;
  
 $scope.variable2 = "showname()";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="name">
<button type="button" ng-click="variable1" tabindex="10003" >Not working 1 </button>

<button type="button" ng-click="$scope[variable2]()" tabindex="10003" >Not working 2 </button>

<button type="button"  ng-click="variable2" tabindex="10003" >Not working 3 </button>

<button type="button" ng-click="showname()" tabindex="10003"> working </button>
</div>
```

Comment: how exactly are you planning on using this?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey It is a function variable only. I am just tried with a string variable as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$scope.$eval` method and invoke the function like `variable2()`.

`$eval` method don't evaluate JavaScript; they evaluate just `AngularJS` expressions.

Also, for the below line

```
$scope.variable1 = $scope.showname;
```

You are just keeping a reference to your `showname` function. You have to invoke it

```
<button type="button" ng-click="variable1()" tabindex="10003" >Not working 1 </button>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("name", function($scope) {

 $scope.showname = function()
 {
 alert("Ramesh");
 }
 
  $scope.variable1 = $scope.showname;
  
  $scope.variable2 = $scope.$eval("showname");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="name">
<button type="button" ng-click="variable1()" tabindex="10003" >Not working 1 </button>

<button type="button" ng-click="variable2()" tabindex="10003" >Not working 2 </button>

<button type="button"  ng-click="variable2()" tabindex="10003" >Not working 3 </button>

<button type="button" ng-click="showname()" tabindex="10003"> working </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect :) ..is it possible to do  this without `eval()`??

Comment: using eval is really a bad practice

Comment: @RameshRajendran, I updated my answer with a better method.

Comment: @Sajeetharan, I know but in javascript are a lot of workarounds such as `apply` method or others . I updated my answer using `$scope.$eval` method.

Comment: What's the difference between them?

Comment: @RameshRajendran, have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671471/angular-js-how-does-eval-work-and-why-is-it-different-from-vanilla-eval

Comment: @RameshRajendran it evaluates AngularJS expressions, so it knows that `showname` belongs to `$scope`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="variable1()" tabindex="10003" >Now it'll work 1 </button>
```

[Working plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/6lE1xbLPWTgDxXMIeIpf?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.showname` has function reference. So just assign it to your variable like

```
$scope.variable1 = $scope.showname
```

And then call in ng-click like `valiable1()`

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("name", function($scope) {

 $scope.showname = function()
 {
 alert("Ramesh");
 }
 
  $scope.variable1 = $scope.showname;
  
  $scope.variable2 =  $scope.showname;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="name">
<button type="button" ng-click="variable1()" tabindex="10003" >Not working 1 </button>

<button type="button" ng-click="variable2()" tabindex="10003" >Not working 2 </button>

<button type="button"  ng-click="variable1()" tabindex="10003" >Not working 3 </button>

<button type="button" ng-click="showname()" tabindex="10003"> working </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$scope`, use the `this` keyword:

> Erroneous
>
> ```
> <button type="button" ng-click="$scope[variable2]()" tabindex="10003" >
>      Not working 2 
> </button>
> ```

Instead use:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="this[variable2]()" tabindex="10003" >
     working
</button>
```

It is possible to access the context object using the identifier `this`.

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Expression context](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#context).