# Directive on same element as ng-repeat, need ng-repeat to run first and use its value

Tags: html, angularjs, video.js, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to hook up the `video.js` library into my app. On one part of the app, users have the ability to upload files which may contain videos, so when output, I am using an `ng-repeat` to loop through the video uploads, and output an `HTML5` video tag. I now want to attach a directive to the video tag so that `video.js` can be used with it.

My video output is defined as

```
<video ng-src="{{video.url}}" ng-repeat="video in post.attachments.video" type="{{video.mimetype}}" controls preload="metadata" id="video_{{video.id}}" video>
```

For my `video` directive, I essentially just want to run the `videojs` function to set it up, so I want to call

```
videojs(attrs.id, {
    controls: true,
    preload: "metadata",
    techOrder: ["flash"]
  }, function() {});
```

This is being called, but the issue I'm having is that the `ng-repeat` hasn't finished everything yet when this directive is called, such that the `attrs.id` is still `video_{{video.id}}` rather than something like `video_23` which I want.

How can I wait until the `ng-repeat` has finished its thing before my video directive runs so I know I can use the ID attribute?

I'm currently using Angular 1.1.4.

Right now, my directive has

```
app.directive("video", function($parse) {
  "use strict";
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {

      videojs(attrs.id, {
        controls: true,
        preload: "metadata",
        techOrder: ["flash"]
      }, function() {});
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Could you please post the code for your directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that string interpolation has not been performed at the time you are trying to access the interpolated values.  You can use `attrs.$observe(...)` in order to accomplish this.  Here is a [link](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#Attributes) to the AngularJS documentation (or read it below).

```
...
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
  attrs.$observe('id', function() {
    videojs(attrs.id, {
      controls: true,
      preload: "metadata",
      techOrder: ["flash"]
    }, function() {});
  });
}
...
```

I have also created a [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/JA3wDfNrBYnRYdzJ6RT6/preview) showing this behavior.

**Edit**: Updated with correct answer.

**Edit 2**: From the Angular documentation:

> Use `$observe` to observe the value changes of attributes that contain
>   interpolation (e.g. `src="{{bar}}"`). Not only is this very efficient
>   but it's also the only way to easily get the actual value because
>   during the linking phase the interpolation hasn't been evaluated yet
>   and so the value is at this time set to undefined.

Comment: Getting the error `Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 7 of the expression [video_{{video.id}}] starting at [{{video.id}}].`

Comment: Made some progress, turns out the expression format was wrong for eval to work, so I've changed it now to `'video_' + video.id` which should work, but now the scope it is running in is not the same scope that ng-repeat is creating. Any way of accessing it?

Comment: @PaReeOhNos I have updated my answer and provided an example showing how to solve this.

Comment: Ah that works! And no need for the $timeout hack in the solution I posted! :D My concern with the $observe method however, is will that constantly be watching the attribute?

Comment: I don't think so. `$observe` is not the same as `$watch`, I am fairly certain that it just waits for the attribute to be set.  According to the Angular documentation: `Use $observe to observe the value changes of attributes that contain interpolation (e.g. src="{{bar}}"). Not only is this very efficient but it's also the only way to easily get the actual value because during the linking phase the interpolation hasn't been evaluated yet and so the value is at this time set to undefined.`

Comment: What happens if the attributes that you're trying to observe is on a child DOM element? In fact that's my current situation. I have a directive on a parent surrounding an ng-repeat requiring access to an attribute set on the child which is determined after ng-repeat? I'm currently using $timeout hack, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Finally have a solution. It's not the nicest (due to angulars lack of callbacks) but it's working. My final directive is

```
app.directive("video", function($timeout) {
  "use strict";
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    compile: function(cElm, cAttrs) {
      return function postLink(scope, elm, attrs) {
        // We have to wait until it's actually rendered. Stupid angular with no callback!
        $timeout(function() {
          videojs(scope.$eval(attrs.video), {
            controls: true,
            preload: "metadata",
            techOrder: ["flash"]
          }, function() {});
        })
      }
    }
  };
});
```

I also had to change the definition of my html to

```
<video ng-src="{{video.url}}" ng-repeat="video in post.attachments.video" type="{{video.mimetype}}" controls preload="metadata" id="video_{{video.id}}" video="'video_' + video.id">
```

Notice the addition of the expression in the `video` attribute, as the expression used in the `id` attribute couldn't be used in `eval`.

I also had to make use of the annoying `$timeout` hack, as trying to initialise video.js on the element ID wasn't working as angular hadn't finished rendering the element, so when video.js tried to find the element with that ID in the DOM, it didn't match anything. Using `$timeout` fixed this although I'm not overly keen on it.

If anyone has a nicer solution to this then I'm all ears :)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a `priority` to the directive. From the docs [AngularJS: Directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> priority - When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element, sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives are applied. The priority is used to sort the directives before their compile functions get called. Priority is defined as a number. Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first. The order of directives with the same priority is undefined. The default priority is 0.

EDIT:
Actually, this looks pretty similar to this question: [How to get evaluated attributes inside a custom directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371159/angularjs-how-to-get-evaluated-attributes-inside-a-custom-directive)

Comment: Have tried the priority and set it to 1010 as ng-repeat runs at 1000. Nothing changed

Comment: You would want to be lower priority than `ng-repeat` anyway.

Comment: Surely the default of 0 is a lower priority then, so setting is explicitly makes no difference? Just tried with 10 and still nothing

Comment: I looked at that but was concerned about the creation of a new scope when in conjunction with ng-repeat which creates its own scope anyway?

Comment: @PaReeOhNos I've included a link to a similar question.

Comment: Yeah cheers. Just tried it but now angular is complaining with `Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 7 of the expression [video_{{video.id}}] starting at [{{video.id}}].`