# Pass params in ng-include

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, templates

I am new to angularjs. I have a requirement where I am using a same radio button again and again in each partial html. So, I want to make it as a common template and use it in other partial templates.

```
<ng-include src="'partial-htmls/toolbox/radio-button.html'"></ng-include>
```

Which shows the radio button as follows:

```
Sex :    O Male
         O Female
```

This is fine but I need to change the label, text and number of radio buttons somehow in the `ng-include`. (*which I am thinking to do by passing params somehow*)

I am from background of lodash, where it can be easily handled. I thought there might be a way in angular too.

Please help.

Comment: That looks like an odd usage of ng-include. Why not nested controller?

Comment: @Amit I thought I should use `ng-include` please suggest me what is the best way to handle this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to pass parameters to an `ng-include`.
It *does* have access to the same scope as the HTML it's in, though.

If you need to be able to pass different parameters, you're going to have to use a directive:

```
angular.module("myModule")
.directive('radioButton', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            pass: "=",
            some: "@",
            properties: "="
        },
        templateUrl: 'app/directives/views/radio-row.html',
        controller: ["$scope", function ($scope) {
            // Isolated $scope here
        }]
    };
}]);
```

```
<radio-button pass="parentScopeObject" some="Literal string" properties="parentScopeSomething"></radio-button>
```

Comment: You *could* put an `ng-controller` or `ng-init` on the same element as the `ng-include`, but a directive would be better.

Comment: This worked when I wrapped  the custom attributes in single quotes. like this: `pass="'parentScopeObject'" some="'Literal string'" properties="'parentScopeSomething'"`. Thanks!!

Comment: @Mr_Green: For strings you need to use "@", then you don't need the extra quotes. Basically, `"@"` will literally take the contents of the passed parameter, and `"="` will interpret the argument as a variable name in the parent scope. [This question explains that quite well.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712147/differences-among-in-angular-directive-scope)