# Define function inside Angular directive's isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm writing a custom `<pagination>` directive, which will return elements responsible for changing the current page and pagination settings (e.g. how many items will be displayed per page). The directive has isolated scope (to make it more reusable).

Inside the directive template I need to call functions like `changePage()` or `changePaginationSettings()`. The only way to pass a function inside the isolated scope I've found so far is define the function in the controller.

*mainController.js*

```
module.controller("mainController", function($scope) {
    $scope.changePage = function() { ... };
});
```

and then pass it to directive as an attribute:

*pagination.js*

```
module.directive("pagination", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
           changePage: "="
        },
        templateUrl: "templates/pagination.html"
    }
}
```

*pagination.html*

```
<pagination change-page="changePage">
```

This looks very ugly to me, because it's splitting related code into 2 unrelated files. That is `changePage()` function should be defined in the *pagination.js* file, not in *mainController.js*.

I'd think something like that should be possible:

*pagination.js*

```
module.directive("pagination", function() {
    function changePage() { ... };

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
           changePage: changePage
        },
        templateUrl: "templates/pagination.html"
    }
}
```

But such code is producing a (meaningless to me) error: `Error: definition.match is not a function`.

**Is there a way to achieve that? I mean to pass a function defined in the same file inside an isolated scope of directive.**

I've read [AngularJS Directive Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) but they don't even list what are legal values in `scope` object of a directive, only give some "=", "&" and "@" examples.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only legal values for an isolated scope object definition are strings which begin with `&`, `@`, or `=`. (You can also follow these symbols with the name of the property on the parent scope should you want the property name to differ within the directive.<sup>1</sup>) In this instance you want to use the `=` symbol as this indicates that Angular should "bind `changePage` on the directive scope to `changePage` on the parent scope". Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21714971/2039244) for more details.

You're right that it is ugly having to pass this function in via an attribute on the directive, however this is the nature of having an isolated scope. You might consider having the `changePage` and other related methods in a service, as you can then inject this as a dependency.

**Edit**

Without an isolate scope you could do the following:

```
module.directive("pagination", function() {    
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "templates/pagination.html",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            // scope.changePage is available from the directive's parent $scope
        }
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Example: `{ 'nameInDirective': '=nameOnParent' }`

Comment: So there is no way to define a new scope value inside a directive itself, right? BTW I don't see how allowing that would violate an *isolated scope* concept. Solution using service seems to be much nicer than defining the values inside a controller. Thanks for suggesting it.

Comment: You can do whatever you like with the directive's `$scope`, the only difference with an isolate scope is that the directive inherits properties defined explicitly by you and none others. Access a directive's `$scope` just like you would in a controller, e.g.: `link: function(scope, elem, attrs) { ... }`

Comment: I've asked the question in my previous comment in the wrong way. What I meant was: "So there is no way to define some new value inside a directive? - the only values available inside a directive are the ones that were passed to it via attributes **and** bound to the  isolated scope explicitly by me."

Comment: Not sure if you are still posing the question? But yes, that is correct.

Comment: Yes, that was a question : ). I wanted to make sure my thinking is correct. Thanks for clarification and answering my question.

Answer (score 2):

As user sdgluck answers correctly you can extend the directive scope in the link function and thus keep your code clean and separate. Following sample is a little more complete but it boils down to the same result. It allows you to define an element as below. **Be aware that all attributes are interpreted as objects, and, if you want to pass a string value you have to put the extra quotes around that value (or you'll get an undefined value for that attribute)**

```
<my-button someattr="'my text'"></my-button>

angular.module('test', []);

angular.module('test').controller('testctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.someValue = '';
});

angular.module('test').directive('myButton', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<button>{{getText()}}</button>',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      someattr: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elements, attrs){
      scope.getText = function(){
        return scope.someattr;
      };
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I defined my function inside a custom directive instead of defining the function inside a controller.
Here you can see an example:

Your HTML:

```
<my-custom-directive></my-custom-directive>
```

Your directive definition:

```
.directive("myCustomDirective", myCustomDirectiveHanlder)

function myCustomDirectiveHandler() {
    return {
        templateUrl: "/app/templates/myCustomDirectiveTemplate.html",
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, elements, attrs) {
            //your code here
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

here you have a sample configuration.

main controller

```
module.controller("mainController", function($scope) {
    $scope.changePage = function() { ... };
});
```

let's say it's `index.html` and you should have the directive like that

```
<pagination change-page="changePage()">
```

and your directive should be like below

```
module.directive("pagination", function() {
    function changePage() { ... };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
           changePage: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: "templates/pagination.html"
    }
}
```

and your pagination.html

```
<div ng-click="changePage()"></div>
```

this will bind to your main controller's `changePage` function.

Comment: That is almost the same as the code I provided. And what's the most important you still define `changePage()` function inside a controller, which is something that I'd like to avoid and the reason of my  question - I've asked is there a way to define `changePage()` inside a directive rather than in a controller.

Comment: ok..anyway you would have missed the isolate scope when you need it, as a result of that you can not pass params from parent scope to your directive

Comment: I didn't want to pass anything from the parent scope. What I'd want is to define a new value (in my case a function) inside the isolated scope of a directive.