# Controller variables don't update when using them in another controller of an mdPanel passed in via locals

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have a method in a controller called `showFilterMenu(e)` which opens up an $mdPanel and passes the locals `this.allOptions` and `this.selectedOptions` in.

```
class MainController{
    constructor(){
        this.filterPanelRef;
        this.allOptions = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
        this.selectedOptions = [];
        this.filter = () => {
            // do some logic to filter down a list using this.selectedOptions against this.allOptions.
        }
    }

    showFilterMenu(e){
        this.filterPanelRef = this.$mdPanel.create({
            attachTo: angular.element(document.body),
            controller: 'filterController',
            controllerAs: 'filterCtrl',
            bindToController: true, //redundant since default is true
            template: require('./filter/filter.html'),
            locals: {
                allOptions: this.allOptions,
                selectedOptions: this.selectedOptions,
                filter: this.filter
            },
            clickOutsideToClose: true,
            escapeToClose: true,
            focusOnOpen: true
        });

        this.filterPanelRef.open();
    }
}
```

In my filter template file I make use of a directive, so I continue to pass through the locals from the `MainController`:

```
<multi-select-filter
    options="filterCtrl.allOptions"
    selected-options="filterCtrl.selectedOptions"
    on-filter="filterCtrl.filter">   
</multi-select-filter>
```

My directive has the following options set:

```
//...
restrict = 'E';
template = MultiSelectFilterHtml;
controller = 'multiSelectFilterController';
controllerAs = 'multiSelectFilterCtrl';
bindToController = true;
replace = true;
scope = {
    selectedOptions: '=',
    options: '=',
    onFilter: '='
};
```

and the `MultiSelectFilterHtml` looks like:

```
<md-input-container class="multi-select-filter" md-no-float>
    <md-select
        ng-change="multiSelectFilterCtrl.onFilter()"
        ng-model="multiSelectFilterCtrl.selectedOptions"
        multiple>
        <md-option
            ng-value="option"
            ng-repeat="option in multiSelectFilterCtrl.options>
            {{option}}
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

Everything works and initializes properly, but when selecting options in the list, they bubble back up to the filterController but then don't change in the MainController. It's acting like I am passing in a copy of this.allOptions and this.selectedOptions into the mdPanel.

Basically when my model updates in the multi select filter directive, I want it to be modifying the selectedOptions of the MainController, since my filter method uses that variable when filtering and right now it is always an empty array.

I must be missing something.

Comment: which version of angular material are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult without a jsfiddle but I think your bindings are incorrect for the **onFilter** binding in the **multiSelectFilter** directive scope, try using '&' instead.

this answer should give you more information https://stackoverflow.com/a/21714971/1248388