# how does $parse work in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, directive

I've managed to play with directive attribute listener without using isolated scope (`$watch`, `$observe` and `$parse` - a pleasure) but I experience difficulties understanding the last one.

Here's my html :

```
<div active="setActiveNav(number1)"></div>
```

And my directive :

```
link: function(scope,elem,attr){
    scope.myFunction = $parse(attr.active);
    ...
}
```

But can you explain how do I fire the function passed in my 'active' attribute ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371159/how-to-get-evaluated-attributes-inside-a-custom-directive) for a complete answer to your question

As a sumary you have plenty of choices depending on how you want your directive to work

- pass it to the directive directly `scope: { active: "&active" }`
- `$parse(attr.active)(scope))`
- `scope.$eval(attr.active)`