# angular directive attributes not evaluated

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've tried the answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371159/how-to-get-evaluated-attributes-inside-a-custom-directive) but no luck (I'm using angularjs 1.3). My problem is two part

1) Complex attributes are not being passed as objects despite using '=' (see code below) in scope

2) the function that should evaluate to provide one-way binding is also being passed as string instead

sample use,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="RestEditCtrl.saveRestaurantDetails();">
    <smart-btn-label btn-state="RestEditCtrl.ajaxState(RestEditCtrl.restaurant.id)"
        when-normal="{label: 'Save', icon: 'glyphicon-floppy-disk' }"
        when-active="{label: 'Saving...', icon: 'glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-spin-animate'}"
        when-success="{label: 'Saved!',   icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved'}"
        when-error="{label: 'Try saving again',  icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign'}"></smart-btn-label>
</button>
```

directive code,

```
angular.module("app")
    .directive('smartBtnLabel', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',           
            scope: {
                btnState: '&', // not working, @ evaluates but that defeats my purpose
                whenActive: '=', //  not evaluating any which way, it always comes as string
                whenError: '=',
                whenSuccess: '=',
                whenNormal: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                console.log(attrs);
                var curState = "normal",
                    curLabel = attrs.whenNormal ? attrs.whenNormal.label : "",
                    curIcon = attrs.whenNormal ? attrs.whenNormal.icon : "";

                if (attrs.btnState) curState = attrs.btnState;

                if(curState == "active"){
                    curLabel = attrs.whenActive  ? attrs.whenActive.label : "";
                    curIcon = attrs.whenActive ? attrs.whenActive.icon : ""
                } else if(curState == "success"){
                    curLabel = attrs.whenSuccess ? attrs.whenSuccess.label : "";
                    curIcon = attrs.whenSuccess ? attrs.whenSuccess.icon : ""
                } else if(curState == "error"){
                    curLabel = attrs.whenError  ? attrs.whenError.label : "";
                    curIcon = attrs.whenError  ? attrs.whenError.icon : ""
                }

                scope.curLabel = curLabel;
                scope.curIcon = curIcon;
            },
            template: '<span aria-hidden="true" ng-show="curIcon" class="glyphicon {{curIcon}}" ></span>' +
                      '<span ng-show="curLabel">&nbsp;{{curLabel}}</span>'
        };
    });
```

What am I doing wrong here? :-(

---

**Solution**

Thanks to PSL, here is what I ended up with:

```
angular.module("app")
    .directive('smartBtnLabel', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',           
            scope: {
                btnState: '&', 
                whenActive: '&',
                whenError: '&',
                whenSuccess: '&',
                whenNormal: '&'
            },
            controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
                var vm = this;
                vm.props = {icon: "", label: ""};

                var _setProperties = function () {
                    var _btnState = "normal";

                    if ($scope.btnState) _btnState = $scope.btnState();

                    if (_btnState == "active" && $scope.whenActive) vm.props = $scope.whenActive();
                    else if (_btnState == "success" && $scope.whenSuccess) vm.props = $scope.whenSuccess();
                    else if (_btnState == "error" && $scope.whenError) vm.props = $scope.whenError();
                    else if ($scope.whenNormal) vm.props = $scope.whenNormal();
                };

                if($scope.btnState){
                    $scope.$watch($scope.btnState, function () {
                        _setProperties();
                    });
                }

                _setProperties();
            }],
            controllerAs : "smartBtnLabelCtrl",            
            template: '<span aria-hidden="true" ng-show="smartBtnLabelCtrl.props.icon" class="glyphicon {{smartBtnLabelCtrl.props.icon}}" ></span>' +
                      '<span ng-show="smartBtnLabelCtrl.props.label">&nbsp;{{smartBtnLabelCtrl.props.label}}</span>'
        };
    });
```

Comment: I think PSL did a great job answering your question, I was preparing this plunker and I felt it might add 2 cents, http://plnkr.co/edit/HDiiSikmGN1CYLzStoJq?p=preview
Also this is a valuable read on the subject http://blog-it.hypoport.de/2013/11/06/passing-functions-to-angularjs-directives/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *1) Complex attributes are not being passed as objects despite using '=' (see code below) in scope*

That is because you are getting them as `attrs.whenNormal` which is a string (JSON). You instead just need to access it from scope, i.e `scope.whenNormal`. It would just be same as `scope.$eval(attrs.whenNormal)` or `JSON.parse(attrs.whenNormal)//provided your JSON is valid`.
 But the 2 way binding here doesn't make much sense though.

> *2) the function that should evaluate to provide one-way binding is also being passed as string instead.*

That is because when you use function binding they get evaluated as getter with bound values (you specified bound value as `RestEditCtrl.restaurant.id`). Inorder to access the value, provided the function `ajaxState` returns something,  you need to do `curState = scope.btnState();` instead of `curState = attrs.btnState`, basically evaluate the getter to get the value.

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/E3AEsdyUWoIPQyYYMS4r?p=preview)**

Comment: Don't forget to declare scope: {whenNormal: '='}