# How can I avoid defining an implicit interface for passing data into my directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I often use [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to add multiple instances of a directive. For example,

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in list">
  <div my-directive></div>
</div>
```

Inside of `myDirective`, `obj` is available via the scope. Then in the directive's template I can display some data.

```
<div>{{obj.someText}}</div>
```

This works great until I want to use that directive in multiple places. Then I realize that I've implicitly defined an interface for `myDirective`: the data *must* be passed into the scope as an object named `obj`. It doesn't feel right. It feels accidental. It's not clearly documented.

Is there any way around this?

The only way to avoid this that I could think of is worse. It would be to iterate over the keys in the scope and looking for values which don't start with `$`. But if you find more than one key then you're hosed.

Perhaps my entire approach for passing data is just wrong.

Comment: have you tried isolating the directive scope?. Also please share your directive code

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12372494/1522169

Comment: Read the [guide about directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) - it will help you understand how directives are used and defined, and the issues of not using isolate scope.

Comment: Read [https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive)