# Angular display product info in modal after clicking an ng-repeat thumb

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have just started learning angular! I have a 'quick view' button on my list of product thumbnail images, the button and images are generated using angular ng-repeat. I need to display the appropriate product description/price etc (from my json file) in a modal when clicking on 'quick view' but can't get anything to show. I was wanting to possibly filter the products using their product code, as this is unique to each item. Any help would be much appreciated.

My html:

```
  <div ng-repeat="product in store.products">
    <div class="item col-md-3 col-xs-12">
        <div class="product-image-wrapper text-center">
            <div class="product">
                <div class="image">  
                    <div class="quickview">
                        <a title="Quick View" class="btn btn-xs  btn-quickview" data-target="#product-details-modal" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="selectedProduct = product"> Quick View </a>
                    </div><!--quickview-->
                    <a href="#"><product-image></product-image></a>
                </div><!--image-->
                <p><span class="red"><product-title></product-title></span><br>
                </p>
            </div><!--product-->
        </div><!--product-image-wrapper text-center-->
    </div><!--item col-md-3 col-xs-12-->
</div><!--ng repeat-->
```

× 
                    
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            
                        
                    
            
        
    
JS

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('store-products', []);

app.directive('productGallery', function($scope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'includes/product-gallery.html',
    scope: {
      product: '=',
    },
    controller: function() {
      this.current = 0;
      this.setCurrent = function(imageNumber) {
        this.current = imageNumber || 0;
      };
    },
    controllerAs: 'gallerymain'
  };
});

app.directive('productImage', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'includes/product-image.html',
    controller: function() {
      this.current = 0;
      this.setCurrent = function(imageNumber) {
        this.current = imageNumber || 0;
      };
    },
    controllerAs: 'gallery'
  };
});

  app.directive('productTitle', function (){
    return {
      restrict:'E',
      templateUrl: 'includes/product-title.html'
      scope: {
        product: '=',
      },
    };
  });

  app.directive("productDescriptions", function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: "includes/product-description.html"
      scope: {
        product: '=',
      },
    };
  });

})();
```

JSON

```
[
  {
    "name": "Up in Flames",
    "description": "Covered in dragon scales, this rashguard has a full graphical back showing the flame surrounded dragon itself.",
    "price": 24.99,
    "code": "FLAME",
    "images": [
      "images/products/flames/front.jpg",
      "images/products/flames/back.jpg",
      "images/products/flames/close.jpg"
    ],
    "reviews": []
  },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment that sets the selected product, inside your `ng-repeat`, actually creates the `selectedProduct` on a [child scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs?lq=1).  So it is likely inaccessible to your modal markup.  You can avoid this by assigning the selected product to an object property:

`ng-click="store.selected = product"`

I also noticed that you defined [isolated scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12372494/1245971) variables for the product in your directive definition, but you didn't pass the product in.  That should be done with attributes in your html:

`<product-image product="product"></product-image>`

Here is a working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/WKLnEaE7uU85r1CXIWlg?p=preview

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I have been using the above, but was wondering how I would have my data feed in through my JSON file, I was using the below previously, but cant seem to slot it in now? 

      $http.get('store-products.json').success(function(data){
        store.products = data;
      });

Comment: @wickedwicca, I think your problem was that `store.products` should be `$scope.store.products`.  I have updated the plunkr to demonstrate reading products from a JSON file.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I am still plodding away at this. My final problem is getting my product gallery to display. Basically the images only display when I use an ng-repeat, which then displays all the product galleries. How do you display only the selected gallery?  I have <product-gallery ></product-gallery> with my code being: <div class='gallery' ng-show="product.images.length">
 <div class="img-wrap">
     <img ng-src="{{product.images[gallerymain.current]}}" />
 </div> </div>  .  I am lost again and have tried various store.selected on the gallery/images to no avail. thanks x

Comment: Hi @wickedwicca, let me suggest that you accept my answer (by clicking the checkmark), since the original question has been addressed.  Then, open a new question for the selected gallery issue.  In addition, if you create a plunker demonstrating the problem, I am certain you will get an answer within an hour.

Comment: ok sorry - totally new to posting stuff in here so not sure of the etiquette… cheers will do

Comment: No problem!  I think I understand what you were asking, now that I have read it in the new question.  Thanks for creating the demo on plunker.