# AngularJS : directive watch attribute expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, watch

I want a directive to watch the result of an attribute expression such as:

```
<div scroll-if="test === selectedTest"></div>
```

So that it can then react to the change and scroll to the particular element. I seem to be struggling to find out how I can watch for changes to that expression.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get evaluated attributes inside a custom directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371159/how-to-get-evaluated-attributes-inside-a-custom-directive)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `$watch`:

```
app.directive('scrollIf', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {

      var actionScroll = function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if(newVal!==oldVal) {
          console.log("scrolling");
        }
      }

      scope.$watch(attributes.scrollIf, actionScroll);
    }
  }
});
```

`$watch` can evaluate the attribute expression `scroll-if`, the `actionScroll` listener will run if this expression is true.

Is necessary to add the condition `newVal!==oldVal`, because `actionScroll` always runs the first time. This is explained in the [$watch documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Comment: `newVal!=oldVal` should be `newVal !== oldVal`