# Angularjs | how to get an attribute value from element in which controller is defined

Tags: angularjs, dom

I'm still fighting with simple things in Angular. I have jQuery and Backbonejs background, so please do not yell on me. I try hard to understand differences

I have HTML in which from rails is given ID of project as data-project-id:

```
<div data-ng-controller="ProjectCtrl as ctrl" data-project-id="1" id="project_configuration">
```

Is there any chance to get access to this attribute? I need it to my API calls...

Comment: You can use jqlite provided by angularjs which is an alternative for jQuery in angular realm, however you might want to do this in some other way reading data from HTML is not angular way you want to make the model do it except when you're dealing with directives.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To access an elements attributes from a controller, inject `$attrs` into your controller function:

HTML

```
<div test="hello world" ng-controller="ctrl">
</div>
```

Script

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($attrs) {
  alert($attrs.test); // alerts 'hello world'
});
```

In your example, if you want to get data-project-id:

```
$attrs.projectId
```

Or if you want to get id:

```
$attrs.id
```

Demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('ctrl', function($attrs) {
  alert($attrs.test);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" test="hello world">
  
</div>
```

Comment: for me $attrs are undefined, do you have any working fiddle to show?

Comment: You're assuming they are working with a custom directive.
This would probably be why $attrs is undefined. since they may just be in a view's controller instead of a directive's controller.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular world you should use directives to manipulate with DOM elements. Here a nice explanation how to get attribute value from custom directive ([How to get evaluated attributes inside a custom directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371159/how-to-get-evaluated-attributes-inside-a-custom-directive)).

But if you still want to get it's value from controller you are able to use jQuery as well `$('#project_configuration').data('project-id')`

Comment: It is not a good practice to use jquery from inside your controller. Directive is the best place to use jquery.