# how can i get the data-something attribute with angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to access the `{{ test.data('something') }}` however it does not work.

```
<select ng-model="test">
    <option data-something="mySomething" value="blahblah">blahblah</option>
</select>
```

Is there some way i can access it?

I am using angular 1.3.14 ( current latest )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just assign the variable to the attribute, you can always access the variable. That is also how angular is meant to be used:

controller:

```
// Reference to mySomething
$scope.mySomething = "Some value";
```

view:

```
<select ng-model="test">
    <option data-something="mySomething" value="blahblah">blahblah</option>
</select>
```

When you have multiple options (for example an ng-options) you can do the following:

controller:

```
$scope.myOptions = [
    { mySomething: "Something", value: "1", text: "Value 1" },
    { mySomething: "Something else", value: "2", text: "Value 2"}
];

$scope.doSomething = function() {
    console.log($scope.test.mySomething);
}
```

view:

```
<select ng-options="opt.value as opt.text for opt in myOptions"
        ng-model="test"
        ng-change="doSomething()">
</select>
```

To access the attribute's value inside a directive, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371159/how-to-get-evaluated-attributes-inside-a-custom-directive) on SO

Comment: yes, but lets say i have more then one option? how would i know what is the selected one? there data-something attribute may have different values

Comment: See edited answer. You can bind objects to a select and get the selected object through the `ng-model`