# How to mix ngClass Map Syntax and Boolean Operators

Tags: angularjs, debugging, ng-class, boolean-operations

How can I use `ngClass` map syntax with the `&&` and `!` boolean operators?

```
<div class="tbTileContent"
    ng-class=  
    "{'highlight': ((obj.Count == 1 &&  
         setActionType != 1 && setActionType != 20 )},[obj.BackgroundColor,obj.ColumnColor]">
```

Does not work. Is this possible some other way?

Comment: Perhaps copy your div to an angular page and see what happens?

Comment: nothing happend , and it's not working

Comment: Your code does not look syntactically correct, with 2 `((` but 1 `)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get evaluated attributes inside a custom directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371159/how-to-get-evaluated-attributes-inside-a-custom-directive)

Answer (score 0):

Use equality checks with reference to the `rootScope` to simplify debugging, and use the developer tool to check CSS specificity:

```css
.foo { color: red; }
.bar { color: blue; }
.baz { color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
  function bar($rootScope)
    {
    $rootScope.conditionA = true;
    $rootScope.conditionB = function() { return true; };
    }
  
  angular.module('foo',[]);
  angular.module('foo').run(bar);
</script>
<div ng-app="foo">
  <div class="existing" ng-class="{baz: conditionA && conditionB(), foo: conditionA, bar: conditionB()}">
    Hi
  </div>
</div>
```

> Run blocks are the closest thing in Angular to the main method. A run block is the code which needs to run to kickstart the application. It is executed after all of the services have been configured and the injector has been created. Run blocks typically contain code which is hard to unit-test, and for this reason should be declared in isolated modules, so that they can be ignored in the unit-tests.

**References**

- [AngularJS Developer Guide: Modules - Run Blocks](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#run-blocks)
- [AngularJS Source: ngClassSpec.js - 'should support adding multiple classes conditionally via a map of class names to boolean'](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ng/directive/ngClassSpec.js#L71)
- [Angular.js Source: parseSpec.js - 'should give higher precedence to equality than to the logical `and` operator'](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ng/parseSpec.js#L1026)