# How to use a angular controller with ion-tab to set badge count?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How to use a controller and assign badge number to a ion-tab using scope variable from the controller ? 
I'm getting error when I tried this-

```
<ion-tab title="Home" badge={{homeBadgeCount}} ...
```

Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression angular

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out that I don't need to use the {{}} expression. Without that it works !!!

```
<ion-tab title="Home" badge=homeBadgeCount ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, you can do it like `badge=homeBadgeCount` but that is not the best solution.

See [w3schools / html attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp) in section "We Suggest: Always Quote Attribute Values" to know why your solution works but is not the best practice.

Moreover, to know why your first try didn't work; I advice you to read these pages:

- [AngularJs directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), the official doc which explain how its parsing works
- [Stackoverflow - AngularJs - how are attributes evaluated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371159/how-to-get-evaluated-attributes-inside-a-custom-directive)

**tl;dr** write `badge="homeBadgeCount"` instead !