# AngularJS plugin initialization after ng repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i am using MaterializeCSS, and have this piece of code:

```
<select>
<option value="" disabled selected>Jump To Season</option>
<option option-item  ng-repeat="item in series.seasons" value="{{item.id}}">
{{item.name}}
</option>
</select>
```

And im using this directive:

```
.directive("optionItem", [function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element) {
        if (scope.$last) {
            $('select').material_select();
        }
    }
};
}]);
```

Now the elements do repeat as many times as necessary, but instead of displaying the $scope.item.name value it is just displaying {{item.name}} as plain text, not as an expression value. How do i overcome this setback? I tried using Material Angular md-select but i also experienced issues with it, every time i clicked the select i can't click on anything in the webpage and nothing happens.

---

IMPORTANT NOTE:
The series.seasons array is fetched via ajax call.

---

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371159/how-to-get-evaluated-attributes-inside-a-custom-directive

Comment: repeat you problen at http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

set `option-item` directive on `select`

```
  <select option-item>
       <option value="" disabled selected>Jump To Season</option>
       <option ng-repeat="item in users" value="{{item.id}}">
           {{item.name}}
        </option>
  </select>
```

and change directive

```
.directive("optionItem", ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            $timeout(function() { // wait ng-repeat
                $('select').material_select();
            })
        }
    };
}]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vorant/q9bkrzfo/5/

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid i still get the correct amount of options, but empty of content. I added a note to my question, the items are retrieved via ajax call. (The ajax call works for sure if i display them as a regular select they work).

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you try using `$timeout()` to see if moving to next digest cycle helps

```
.directive("optionItem", ['$timeout',function ($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element) {
        if (scope.$last) {
            $timeout(function(){
               element.parent().material_select();
            });
        }
    }
};
}]);
```

Note however you may also need to require `ngModel` controller and manage the model changes yourself from within the plugin events

If this doesn't do it create a plunker demo with needed resources to replicate this

Comment: With your code i get similar results, instead of the expression showing up in plain text, i get empty options.