# How to get the value of a custom attribute in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a custom attribute called `test` in angular js. When I write the `test` attribute just beside the ng-controller keyword i.d.

`<div ng-controller="myCon" test="abc"></div>` then I can access that `test` from the controller by using `alert($attrs.test)`. But if I write the custom attribute `test` other than beside of the ng-controller keyword, I can't access that. i.e.

`<div ng-controller="myCon">
   <div test="def"></div>
</div>`

In this case I got ***undefined*** in `alert($attrs.test)`

Full code...

```
<html>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="kumar" >
 <button ng-click="check()" test="def">Click</button>
</div>

 <script>
 var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
 app.directive("test", function() {
  return {
    //template : "<h1>Hello</h1>"
  };
});

 app.controller("kumar",function($scope,$attrs){
    $scope.check=function(){
      alert(JSON.stringify($attrs.test));   //getting undefined. I 
                      //should get def.
  }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That attribute will be accessible only to the controller of test directive

Comment: button is in the div where ng-controller is written. So I think button is under that controller

Comment: Button is in that controller but the directive's attribute is not. To allow parent to access this you'll need to give the parent access to its child's scope. Read about it [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Comment: @ScottHunter see my answer

Answer (score 3):

```
app.directive("test", function() {
  return {
     restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            text: "@test"
        }
  };
});
```

Update your directive scope and add restrict . For better understanding refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371159/how-to-get-evaluated-attributes-inside-a-custom-directive)

Answer (score 0):

You can check it:

```
<html>
<script src="src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js""></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="kumar" >
 <button ng-click="check()" test="def">Click</button>
</div>

 <script>
 var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
 app.directive("test", function() {
  return {
    //template : "<h1>Hello</h1>"
  };
});

 app.controller("kumar",function($scope,$attrs){
    $scope.check=function(){
    var testa=$scope.test;
      alert(JSON.stringify(testa));   //getting undefined. I 
                      //should get def.
  }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the element on click if you pass **$event** in ng-click, i.e. ng-click="check($event)" and can get the attribute from **$event.target**.

Check fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ayusharma/xb63g9ca/

**JS**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.clickMe = function(evt) {
     console.log(evt.target.getAttribute('test'))
   }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <div ng-click="clickMe($event)" test="abc">Click on Me</div>
</div>
```